# What is the meaning of Rev 12?

Tags: revelation

I am baffled because the dragon is depicted the way Babylon- Rome is: the reign of Satan, trying to snatch a child, but this clashes with the fact that after 1260 years the rebellion of of Satan is described, which naturally happened a long time before Rome or Babylon.

Then, again, after he is hurled to the earth, he tries to pursue the woman, who is put in a safe place for 3 and a half times, which can't be years.

All this makes no sense to me, can you say how this is interpreted?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX,  Thanks for this question.

Comment: You should be a little more precise in your question - Rev 12:6 says 1260 DAYS not years.  You also make the implicit assumption that all the material in Rev 12 is in chronological sequence which is not necessarily true.

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan, you surely know that days are universally interpreted ass year, if there is no chronological sequence most doubts vanish,

Comment: First - that interpretation of a day for year is widespread but FAR from universal.  However, if you wish to adopt that understanding then 3½ years would also be 1260 days if there were 30 days to the month.  This would make it the same period as the 42 months (Rev 11:2, 13:4), see also Rev 11:3.  But this is only if you adopt day-for-year principle.

Comment: Compare Revelation 12:9 with Luke 10:18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the eschatological position of the responder. Not everyone will respond the way you might be thinking when you asked the question.

**There are four main views on the interpretation of Revelation.** All have value, and all have been held by orthodox Christians throughout church history.

- The **historical view** takes the position that Revelation has been and is still being fulfilled throughout church history.
- The **preterist view** takes the position that Revelation has already been fulfilled at the destruction of Jerusalem in 70 AD. There are also some partial preterists who say "most" of Revelation has been fulfilled, but there are still some things that have been/will be fulfilled throughout history (close to historical view).
- The **allegorical view** takes the position that Revelation is not a literal book at all, but is a collection of allegories to teach us through metaphor.
- The **futurist view** (most popular today) is that Revelation is to be fulfilled by future events.

There is a great book with a parallel commentary on all four views. [Revelation: Four Views a Parallel Commentary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0840721285) by Steve Gregg.

Comment: Thanks for your precious answer, I regret I cannot vote; can you add a few word on the interpretations of Rev 12 in particular? I read that the most popular identifies the woman with Mary, but don't you think that 3,5 years is really a petty period for History or Heaven?